# Sphinx fails when generating documentation for Django project

Tags: django, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

I'm trying to automatically generate documentation for my Django project using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) with the [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) and [napoleon](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html) extensions.

Using `sphinx-quickstart` I've created the following structure:

```
MyDjangoProject
├── __init__.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── index.rst
├── myfirstapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py
├── mysecondapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py

...
```

I've customized `docs/source/conf.py` to reflect my project structure.

```
import os
import sys

proj_folder = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

sys.path.append(proj_folder)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

import django
django.setup()

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.intersphinx', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode']

# The rest of the default configuration...
```

Then I go to the root of my project and run `sphinx-apidoc -f -o docs/source .`. This adds a `.rst` file for each module to `docs/source`.

Finally I go to `MyDjangoProject` and run `make html`. This fails with an error for each module saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Oskar/git/MyDjangoProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 551, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named MyDjangoProject.myfirstapp
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have added `MyDjangoProject` to the python path, you should import `myfirstapp` as `myfirstapp` instead of `MyDjangoProject.myfirstapp`.